# How to getById in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am newbie in react and redux, trying to fetch data using api, but trying to fetch by id, unfortunately, `id` is undefined in redux logger and no result back from server side,

Here is my code

**My route** `<Route path="/admin/:id" component={AdminPage} />`

**Action**

```
function getAll(id){
    return dispatch =>{
        dispatch(request(id));

        adminService.getAll(id)
        .then( admin => {

            dispatch(success(admin));
            dispatch(alertActions.success('Welcome Back !'));

        },error => {

            dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
            dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));

        });

    };

    function request(id)    { return { type: adminConstants.GETALL_REQUEST, id } }
    function success(admin) { return { type: adminConstants.GETALL_SUCCESS, admin } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: adminConstants.GETALL_FAILURE, error } }
```

**Reducer**

```
export function admin( state={}, action){
    switch(action.type){

        case adminConstants.GETALL_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true, id : action.id };

        case adminConstants.GETALL_SUCCESS:
        return { items: action.admin };

        case adminConstants.GETALL_FAILURE:
        return { error: action.error };

        default:
        return state
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
function getAll(id){

    const requestOptions = {
        method : 'GET',
        headers: authHeader()
    };
    return fetch(`${apiUrl}/admin/${id}`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse)
    .then( data => {  return data; });
}
```

**AdminPage**

```
class AdminPage extends React.Component{



    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.dispatch(adminActions.getAll());
    }

    render(){
        const { admin } = this.props;
        return(
            <div>

                <h3> Admin Panel</h3>

                {admin.items &&
                    <ul>
                        {admin.items.map((data, index) =>
                            <li key={data.id}>
                             email id : {data.email},
                             end date : {data.dateEnd},
                             customerId : {data.customerId}

                            </li>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                }


            </div>
            );
    }
}




function mapStateToProps(state) {

    const { admin } = state;

    return { admin};
}


const connectedAdminPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(AdminPage);
export { connectedAdminPage as AdminPage };
```

**Link on Home page**

```
<Link to="/admin/5c4f69d5259f7d14434b4cb6">Admin</Link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the 'id' in

> Route path="/admin/:id">

then try

```
console.log("mark1",this.props.match.params.id)
```

inside 'AdminPage' component.
If it works then you can pass it to the dispatcher via the component and use inside your function.

For more documentation try https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params.

If this is not what you were asking comment below and I'll edit accordingly. :)

Edit: So here is the solution for the 'AdminPage'

```
class AdminPage extends React.Component{



    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.dispatch(adminActions.getAll(this.props.match.params.id));
    }
...
}
```

Now it should not be undefined in the action, can you confirm?

Comment: id not deliver in server side, id stuck in redux

Comment: reducer GETALL_REQUEST is okey ?

Comment: Can you share AdminPage component? Try console logging things to see which part it is failing at and tell us specifically whether it reached the action, service or reducer. Start with console logging the render method of the AdminPage component that is in your `Route`

Comment: updated,  action     {type: "ADMIN_GETALL_REQUEST", id: undefined}

Comment: So you just need to pass 'this.props.match.params.id' to the 'adminActions.getAll()'. It's missing in your code. Updated my answer